# Windows Sticky Notes unable to type

Tags: sticky-notes

When I create sticky notes, I am able to type and delete text as normal. However, when I save them for the next day, something different happens. I am able to delete text (as well as copy/paste), but cannot add text to sticky notes from the previous day.

As a work-around, I have to create a new sticky note, copy and paste the text over to the new note, delete the old note, and then continue adding text.

I want the notes to be able for me to update them with information each day, but cannot do this due to the notes being locked from typing. I am using an windows in an office setting, so I am not able to download any third-party apps to replace the sticky notes.

Current Windows: Windows 10 Pro, OS build 18363.592
Sticky Notes Version: 3.7.106.0

Answer (score 2):

When you launch Sticky Note, you see your existing note. Right Click on it, open the Note and then you can edit it. You must open it before editing it, but you can edit it.

Comment: I would like to leave the note on my desktop. When I close it and reopen it, I can edit it, but I would like to be able to just leave the note open. When I leave it open on the desktop, and login the next day, I am not able to continue editing the note. This is what I am trying to report about the program.

Comment: Sticky Note is analogous to Word et al, so if you start it, leave it open and no one else has access, then you should be able to edit. If it is in a public network location it may get lock. See it that is the issue

Comment: Closing and re-opening the note worked for me.

Comment: John, yes you should be able to edit it but I cannot, this reduces the usability a lot, they are meant to be quick notes that are retained on the desktop and editable. Closing and reopening is a pain, although it works it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem with notes left open on my desk top the next day. I am also not able to add to or edit the previous notes. I agree that this reduces the usability.
I use the notes to log my time spent on certain jobs for a required form that I fill out at the end of the week. Sometimes, I need to add onto the previous day's note and I am not able to do so.
It seems like this should be a fixable glitch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).